# Bash script issue checking command output

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a bash script that I want to check the output a Linux command
The command is: sudo supervisorctl status

The normal output looks like this:

```
0: tuxtunnel                        RUNNING   pid 563, uptime 11 days, 5:04:19
1: util_pkt_logger                  STOPPED   Oct 11 01:20 PM
2: watchdog                         EXITED    Oct 11 12:03 PM
```

My first attempt of the bash script reads this output from the command and puts each line into an array, unfortunately when I go to check to see if a string is contained in this result, it seems to try and execute the check as a command. My script looks like this

```
    echo "its stopped"
x=$(sudo supervisorctl status)
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
x=(${x})
IFS=$SAVEIFS
for(( i=0; i<${#x[@]}; i++ ))
do
    echo "$i: ${x[$i]}"
    if [$x[$i]] =~"STOPPED" #check if array contains this string
    then
        echo "its stopped"
    fi
done


 exit 0
```

When I try to perform the check that is when things go haywire, I am new to bash scripts, so any help would be appreciated. I am trying to see if the line contains the word STOPPED

Comment: `SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
x=(${x})
IFS=$SAVEIFS` just `IFS=$'\n' x=($x)` in one line. `#check if array contains this string` - print each array element on separate line and just `grep`.

Comment: Your `if` condition syntax is all wrong -- you need double-square-brackets around the expression, no square brackets around `$x` (instead, you need curly braces around the part *after* `$`), and spaces between all syntactic elements. I also like to put double-quotes around variable references, even in cases like this where it doesn't matter: `if [[ "${x[$i]}" =~ "STOPPED" ]]`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: why not just `x=( $(sudo supervisorctl status) )` ? And yes, line by line is so much easier. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than reading the entire output of `supervisorctl` into a single variable and then manipulating the `IFS` variable to break the lines up, try reading one line at a time. Also, instead of matching `STOPPED` anywhere on the line, only look for it in the status column.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  echo ${line}
  fields=( ${line} )
  if [ ${fields[2]} == "STOPPED" ]; then
    echo "It's stopped."
  fi
done < $(sudo supervisorctl status)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to go for a while loop. You can use awk to solve this.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo supervisorctl status | awk '{if ($6 == "STOPPED") print $2" is Stopped";}'
```

Answer (score 0):

gawk utility we can use .Please refer URL 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94047/shell-script-to-print-rows-if-there-is-a-value-in-column-2

cat testout
0: tuxtunnel                        RUNNING   pid 563, uptime 11 days, 5:04:19
1: util_pkt_logger                  STOPPED   Oct 11 01:20 PM
2: watchdog                         EXITED    Oct 11 12:03 PM
3: TEST_log                         STOPPED   OCT 1 11:11AM

gawk '$3=="STOPPED" {print $0}' testout
1: util_pkt_logger                  STOPPED   Oct 11 01:20 PM
3: TEST_log                         STOPPED   OCT 1 11:11AM

Answer (score 0):

This was a brackets issue. This fixed it:
if [[ "${x[$i]}" =~ "STOPPED" ]] thanks to Gordon Davisson